# how to I use SFINAE for function objects with different operator() methods

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, enable-if

I wanted to use SFINAE to function objects. For example:

```
struct functor_1_tag{  };
struct functor_2_tag{  };
struct functor_3_tag{  };

template<typename Graph_t>
struct functor { 
  functor() {  };
  functor(Graph_t& G) : m_G(G) {  } 

  template<typename vertex_t>
  void operator(vertex_t  vertex) { 
    /// do stuff with vertex
  } 
private: 
  Graph_t& m_G;
};

// Similary another 2 functors that have operator()  doing different tasks. 

//Usecase:
// just for 2 functors here 
typedef std::conditional <true, functor_1_tag, functor_2_tag>::type  funct_type;

/// functor --> shud be selected based upon conditional above.?? 
auto func = std::bind(functor<graph>, G, std::placeholders::_1);

// use in algorithm for vertices
std::for_each(vertexset.begin(), vertexset.end(), func );
```

The `do stuff with vertex` ( essentially the `operator()`)  is different based upon the functor tags and I want to overload these three functors based upon tags or any other methods such as `std::conditional, or std::enable_if or any nested condition checker.`

I was able to achieve the same thing for my standard functions. but I am not sure how to do it for functors. The thing is that functors differ only in their operator() implementation and I dont want to overload the operator() methods.

Tag dispatch for functions:

```
 struct func1_tag{ };
 struct func2_tag{ };

 void do_this(int x) 
 {
    do_this_actually( int x, dispatch() );
 }

 do_this_actually(int x, func1_tag) {  //do stuff  }
 do_this_actually(int x, func2_tag) { // ... } 

 typedef   std::conditional<true, func1_tag, func2_tag>::type  dispatch;
```

this is for functions. but I am not sure how to use it for function objects. i tried binding the tags to 2nd arguments of the functor. no luck!

Comment: How is `funct_type` being used here?

Comment: thats what I want to know. how do i use it.. :-/

Comment: Can you show how you did it with regular functions? Also, why do you want to avoid overloading? This is a perfect opportunity for tag-dispatching.

Comment: yep. tag-dispatch is the right way to do this and not overloading. I will update the question with example for functions

Comment: As @0x499602D2 says, it seems like tag dispatch is the way to go - you have even already created the tags! With your current version (and not using tag dispatch) you will need some way to link the tags and the different functor types...

Comment: agreed. i am just not able to link the tags to function objects. it gives a redefinition error (because the functors differ only in the operator() methods.

Comment: So you want to selectively disable/enable operator() with SFINAE? Can you show a small example of what you'd like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure to understand the complexity of your problem, so either I missed the point or you are overcomplicating your case… Why not create different functors and just select which one to use with the conditional?

```
struct functor1 { … };
struct functor2 { … };

using functor = std::conditional<condition, functor1, functor2>::type;

std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), functor());
```

Comment: you are probably right. I shouldnt have complicated the function dispatch methods with function objects. this was a straightforward idea and i simple couldnt think in this direction. this would work for me now. thanks a bunch.